# Horizontal line test in graphs

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, graphing-functions

Given a function $f\colon X \to Y$

i. If a horizontal line test intersects at at most one point, it is **injective**.

ii. If it intersects at more than one point, it is **surjective**.

iii. If it intersects at exactly one point, it is **bijective**.

For example $f(x)=2^x$

Now, my problem is what if you chose $y=-5$, it doesn't intersect with the graph, is it still considered an injective function?

Also, if a graph is injective does it also mean it is automatically bijective?

Comment: See [Horizontal line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test) : "we can decide if it is injective by looking at horizontal lines **that intersect the function's graph**."

Comment: Specifically, "intersects at one point" should be clarified to "intersects at at most one point" since "intersects at exactly one point" is for part iii.

Comment: Oh, I kinda skipped that part, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelBiro so can it have no intersections?

Comment: It is not necessarily true that if a horizontal line intersects the graph of a function more than once, then the function is surjective.  For instance, the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sin x$ is not surjective even though the $x$-axis intersects the graph infinitely many times.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition.**  A function is said to be *injective* if $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$ or, equivalently, $x_1 \neq x_2 \implies f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

**Horizontal Line Test.**  *A horizontal line intersects the graph of an injective function at most once.*

Proof.  Suppose otherwise.  Then there exists a horizontal line $y = k$ and an injective function $f$ whose graph intersects the line $y = k$ at two points, $(x_1, k)$ and $(x_2, k)$, with $x_1 < x_2$.  Then $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = k$.  Since $f$ is injective, $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$, which contradicts our assumption that $x_1 < x_2$.  Thus, a horizontal line can intersect the graph of an injective function at most once.$\blacksquare$

You observed that the line $y = -5$ does not intersect the graph of the function $f(x) = 2^x$.  Notice that this does not contradict the definition of an injective function since we do not have two different $x$-values that produce the same $y$-value.

[image: graph_of_exponential_function]

The function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 2^x$ is injective since for each $y$ in its range, there is exactly one value of $x$ such that $f(x) = y$, namely $x = \log_2 y$.

**Definition.**  A function $f: X \to Y$ is said to be *surjective* if for each $y \in Y$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$, that is, if its range, $f(X) = \{f(x) \mid x \in X\}$, is equal to its codomain, $Y$.

The function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 2^x$ is not surjective since its range, $\text{Ran}_f = (0, \infty)$, is not equal to its codomain, $\mathbb{R}$.

**Definition.**  A function is said to be *bijective* if it is both injective and surjective.

The example $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 2^x$ demonstrates that an injective function is not necessarily a bijective function.

We can transform an injective function into a bijective function by restricting the codomain to equal its range.  For instance, if we restrict the codomain of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 2^x$ to $(0, \infty)$, we create a bijective function $g: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ defined by $g(x) = 2^x$.  Since a function is specified by its domain, its codomain, and its graph (the set of ordered pairs that satisfy the function), $g \neq f$ since the functions $f$ and $g$ have different codomains.

It is not necessarily true that if a horizontal line crosses the graph of a function more than once that the function is surjective.  For instance, the $x$-axis crosses the graph of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sin x$ infinitely many times, but $f$ is not surjective since its range, $\text{Ran}_f = [-1, 1]$, does not equal its codomain, $\mathbb{R}$.

[image: sine_function_graph]

What we can say is that the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \sin x$ is not injective since it fails the Horizontal Line Test.

If a function $f: X \to Y$ is surjective, then for each $k \in Y$, the horizontal line $y = k$ must intersect the graph of $f$ at least once.  Otherwise, there would be no $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = k \in Y$.

If a function $f: X \to Y$ is bijective, then for each $k \in Y$, the horizontal line $y = k$ will intersect the graph of $f$ exactly once since it must intersect the graph of $f$ at least once for the function to be surjective and at most once for the function to be injective.